# Does a dc generator need a flyback diode?

Tags: dc, generator

From what I've read and understand, it makes sense that a dc motor needs a flyback diode to protect the rest of the circuit. I have a much harder time finding an answer about whether or not a dc generator needs one...

I'm doing some experiments that are similar to those I saw online where a model steam engine, driving a dc generator, is used to power an Arduino. So far, I measured that the dc generator can output from 0 to about 11 Vdc. The circuit containing the Arduino that I intend to power with this dynamo draws around 40 mA.

Answer (score 1):

Fly-back.. No. Since you are not switching anything there are no fly-back transients to dissipate.

However, it is still prudent to include a diode in that same location, in the same direction, to protect your circuit in the event that the generator is driven backwards for whatever reason.

Some over-voltage protection would also be warranted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fieeGq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you and Bimpelrekkie below for the replies. I will add in the reverse protection diode. To be extra safe, I am using a 7805 before the Arduino and thus won't need the Zener diode?

Answer (score 0):

The flyback diode is needed when you have a situation where you **suddenly** interrupt the flow of current. For example when using a **transistor** to switch on/off the power to a **motor** or a **relay**.

These devices are **inductive loads**, they have a magnetic coil inside (or more than one) which can **store magnetic energy**. When the current flow is interrupted then this energy cannot gradually decrease and this creates a **high voltage** which damages the switching transistor. A flyback diode absorbs this energy (partly) and so protects the transistor.

In a generator you do not suddenly interrupt the current unless there is a series switch. You probably do not have this switch. Then in principle you do not need the flyback diode. You could however, for safety, add a diode in reverse mode. If for some reason the generator makes the opposite polarity then the diode can protect the rest of the circuit form damage:

[image: schematic]

The diode marked "optional" is just that, optional for extra safety.

The capacitor of 100 uF might be needed to smooth the DC voltage.

In this circuit there are no flyback diodes!

Only reverse voltage protection diodes.